# Perl threading with hash of arrays

Tags: multithreading, perl, share, multidimensional-array

I am trying to share a hash of arrays with threads::shared module as below.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my @allThreads;
share (my %array);

foreach ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
{
    $name = $_;
    push @allThreads, threads->new(\&doWork, $name);
}

foreach my $thread (@allThreads){ $thread->join; } # Wait for all threads to join.

sub doWork
{
    $tempName = shift;
    my @results = `/bin/ls /home/*`;
    doMoreWork($tempName, @results);
}

sub doMoreWork
{
    my $myName = shift;
    my @tempResults = @_;
    foreach (0 .. $#tempResults)
    {
        if($tempResults[$_] =~ /(\w+)/)
        {
            my $x = $1;
            $array{$x} = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
        }
    }
}

foreach (keys %array)
{
    print "$array{$_}->[3]\n";
}
```

I get the following error:

Can't use string ("11") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at myCode.pl.

I need to sort this shared hash of arrays by an array element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `doWork` function is evaluating `@temp` in scalar context.  So it is effectively doing `$array{$tempName} = 11`.

Also you can omit the `temp` variable, since `[ ... ]` already creates an array reference.

```
sub doWork
{
    $tempName = shift;
    $array{$tempName} = [1 .. 11];
}
```

[edit]

This version of doMoreWork runs at least:

```
sub doMoreWork
{
    my $myName = shift;
    my @tempResults = @_;
    if(/(\w+)/)
    {
        my $x = $1;
        share (my @temp);
        @temp = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
        $array{$x} = \@temp;
    }
}
```

...but does not do anything useful because `/(\w+)/` is  not matching anything meaningful.  I cannot tell what you trying to do here...

Comment: @Nemo: I tried

`$array{$tempName} = (1, 2, ..., 11);`

However, it gives this error now:

Useless use of string in void context at myCode.pl

Comment: It assigns the last value, i.e. '11' to $array{$temp}.

Comment: OK. With square brackets, it gives: Invalid value for shared scalar at myCode.pl

Comment: Wait, what is `$name`?  Maybe you could try posting your entire program.  (If this is your entire program, add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top.  Those should always be the first two lines of _every_ Perl script.)

Comment: @Nemo: Please see edits in the code. There're a few other extra variables in the code but that don't affect this part so I have posted only the relevant code. And I have divided into two subroutines doWork and doMoreWork for the sake of organizing the code per functionality.

Comment: It still looks to me like `$name` is never defined.  And running with "use warnings; use strict;" agrees with me.  :-)

Comment: Sorry. More edits in the code. I am able to print keys for %array but not the corresponding values (which are arrays). It seems to be some issue with single level sharing with threads::shared. It actually takes a reference to the array rather than the array itself.

Comment: @Nemo: It worked. Thanks a lot ! Now I will try to figure out why it did.

Comment: "\w will match any of the more than 100_000 word characters in Unicode"
How is that not meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

You can always try using my simplifying project found here https://github.com/PabloK/ThreadedArray
It aims to simplify work over a set of elements in an array.